# Is there a Java ORM equivalent to QSqlTableModel?

Tags: java, orm

i m currently working on a Java Project and just wanted to know if there is something like an automatic object-relational mapping (ORM) in JAVA.

In C++, I used `QSqlTableModel`:

```
 QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
 model->setTable("Table_I_wanna_access");
 model->select();
```

After this three lines i could access the Table_I_wanna_access through the model object.
(Which means i could access data, change data, insert, .....)

So my Question is :
Is there something similar in JAVA?
Or do i have to write my own ORM Class for every table in the Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with QSqlTableModel, but a common ORM for Java is [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org)

The ORM mapping nowadays is performed using annotations eg :

```
@Entity
@Table (name="emp")
class Employee
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="SURNAME", nullable=false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")   // Column name on the Role table
    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return tasks;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID")
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

 }
```

In the example above, classes Role and Department would also be annotated with their information.  The annotations cover all aspects of how your classes map to the database tables (including inheritance structures, cascading behaviour, etc).

Several of these annotations have now become a Java standard called JPA, so you should be able to write your code and run with any complying ORM.  Another one that springs to mind is iBatis (but I've only used Hibernate).

Comment: That's what i thought. So i have to write a Database(DB) Table Model Object on my own. And everytime the DB Table changes i have to change the code. A lot of work for nothing. Think i will first give QT for Java (Jambi) a try.

Comment: There are POJO generating tools out there (like JbossTools for eclipse or http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net .  But if you're developing a system together with a database, then you'll be better off generating your database from your java model rather than the other way round, since the Java model will always be richer than what can be deduced from a database schematic alone - eg, it's difficult for a reverse engineering tool to get the inheritance relationships right.  Have a build script that drops your existing database, creates a new one from the POJOs, then loads the reference data.